# Solve the replacement system

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations

$ \begin{cases}
2x^2+xy^2-2x^2-xy=8  \\
 xy+x+y=9 \\
\end{cases}$

''solution'': 
[image]

Comment: The first equation is just $xy^2-xy=8$, unless you made a typo.

Comment: can you correct  your system?

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote, since the equations are still not fixed and this is still unclear.

Comment: @DonThousand First equation of my solution?

Comment: The first equation in your problem. Is it really supposed to be $2x^2-2x^2$? Regardless of what the question is, I'm pretty sure that your answer is incorrect, since you assumed that $a,b$ are positive integers.

Comment: @DonThousand See my new post

Comment: @OP so what you wrote wasn't right...

Comment: @DonThousand Can you explain why you are not right? I do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner approach: we restructure as follows:$$(x+1)(y+1)=10$$$$(2(x+1)+(y+1)-3)\cdot((x+1)(y+1)+(y+1))=8$$Let $v = x+1$, $w=y+1$. We get $$vw=10$$$$w(2v+w-3)(v+1)=8$$We know that $w\neq0$ by the previous equation, so let $v=\frac{10}w$. The second equation becomes $$w(\frac{20}w+w-3)(\frac{10}w+1)=8$$Solve this for $w$, and then solve for $v$ to finish.

Answer (score 1):

$ y=\frac{9-x}{1+x} $ We got from the second equation
let's substitute it in the first equality $$\Rightarrow $$
$ x(\frac{x-9}{1-x})^2-x\frac{x-9}{1-x}=8$ 
$$2x^3-34x^2+56x-8=0 $$ but this equation has 2 solution $\Rightarrow$ we have 2 pair of solution $(x_1;y_1),(x_2,y_2)$

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation we get
$$x=-\frac{y}{y+1}$$
(The case $y=-1$ must also be considered.) so we get
$$2\left(\frac{-y}{y+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-y}{y+1}\right)^2y^2-2\left(\frac{-y}{y+1}\right)^2+\frac{y^2}{y+1}=8$$
For $y$ we get
$$-{\frac {{y}^{3}-{y}^{2}+8\,y+8}{y+1}}=0$$

Comment: It isn't, you can solve it using the Cardano formula, or use the Newton Raphson method.